# What permission for WKWebView is necessary for both video playback and accelerometer in native Swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, media, wkwebview, ios-permissions

I’m converting an app that is largely based on webviews to `WKWebView`. At first, I was prevented from accessing the accelerometer because of  CORS cross domain policy issues.  When I solved that, the video that would play without a problem, now no longer plays.

How do I get enable both video playback and access to the accelerometer?

Basically if I add this line in the snippet blow:

```
configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")
```

then the accelerometer works, video doesn't. Remove this line, the video plays but instead of the accelerometer enabled screen, an error is displayed.

```
let webView: WKWebView = {
     let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
     configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []
     configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
     configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")

     return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
 }()
```

They were working together with the UIWebview, but with my changes to WKWebView I can't get them to work both together.

Comment: "an error is displayed." what error?

Comment: @Honey The following error: `ERROR:

Local usage with file:// urls is limited due browser security restrictions!

Use a localhost server (like the krpano Testing Server) for local testing!
Just start the krpano Testing Server and refresh this page.`